# Sort 3rd column when others are already sorted

Tags: linux, bash

I have that kind of big file :

```
PB.1060.1_1_1000        Chr1      484     817     20733209        
PB.1060.1_1_1000        Chr1      1       293     20733996       
PB.1060.1_1_1000        Chr1      287     485     20733577      
PB.1060.1_2_1001        Chr1      483     816     20733209
PB.1060.1_2_1001        Chr1      286     484     20733577
```

I need to order the 3rd column and keep the first column which is already version-sorted. I should get :

```
PB.1060.1_1_1000        Chr1      1       293     20733996
PB.1060.1_1_1000        Chr1      287     485     20733577
PB.1060.1_1_1000        Chr1      484     817     20733209
PB.1060.1_2_1001        Chr1      286     484     20733577
PB.1060.1_2_1001        Chr1      483     816     20733209
```

I did `-k1,1 -k3,3n` but like the file is big, the first column is no longer sorted :

```
PB.1060.1_1000_1999
PB.1060.1_1000_1999
PB.1060.1_100_1099
PB.1060.1_100_1099
PB.1060.1_100_1099
PB.1060.1_100_1099
PB.1060.1_100_1099
PB.1060.1_1001_2000
PB.1060.1_1001_2000
PB.1060.1_1002_2001 ...
```

Any help ?

Comment: Seems like you want `-k1,1 -k3,3n ...`

Comment: right now we have 3 different sets of data for the 1st column; please update the question to use a consistent set of data; the sample should demonstrate the current ordering, the wrong ordering generated by your `sort` attempt, and the (correct) expected ordering

Comment: what is the current ordering of the 1st column ... numeric? string? version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions/Understandings:

- 1st column has already been sorted based on a 'V'ersion sort
- we need to maintain the ordering of the 1st column, then sort duplicates by the 3rd column

Adding a few rows to our sample data:

```
$ cat input.dat
PB.1060.1_1_1000        Chr1      484     817     20733209
PB.1060.1_1_1000        Chr1      1       293     20733996
PB.1060.1_1_1000        Chr1      287     485     20733577
PB.1060.1_2_1001        Chr1      483     816     20733209
PB.1060.1_2_1001        Chr1      286     484     20733577
PB.1060.1_100_1099      Chr1      905     423     20733234
PB.1060.1_100_1099      Chr1      1020    523     20734234
PB.1060.1_1000_1999     Chr1      3422    223     20731234
PB.1060.1_1000_1999     Chr1      200     323     20732234
PB.1060.1_1001_2000     Chr1      900     623     20735234
```

One `sort` idea:

```
sort -k1,1V -k3,3n input.dat
```

Where:

- apply a 'V'ersion sort to the 1st column
- sort the 3rd column as a 'n'umber

This generates:

```
PB.1060.1_1_1000        Chr1      1       293     20733996
PB.1060.1_1_1000        Chr1      287     485     20733577
PB.1060.1_1_1000        Chr1      484     817     20733209
PB.1060.1_2_1001        Chr1      286     484     20733577
PB.1060.1_2_1001        Chr1      483     816     20733209
PB.1060.1_100_1099      Chr1      905     423     20733234
PB.1060.1_100_1099      Chr1      1020    523     20734234
PB.1060.1_1000_1999     Chr1      200     323     20732234
PB.1060.1_1000_1999     Chr1      3422    223     20731234
PB.1060.1_1001_2000     Chr1      900     623     20735234
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I missed the 'V'ersion for my 1st column.

Answer (score 1):

As your file is already sorted by its first column, and assuming you do not have too many lines with the same first column value, we could store in memory all lines with the same first column value. As soon as we encounter a new first column value or the end of the file we sort the stored lines by their third column and print them.

With GNU `awk`:

```sh
$ awk -vi=1 '
    function sort(a, b) {
      n = asort(b, c)
      for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for(j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
          if(b[j] == c[i]) {
            print a[j]
            break
          }
        }
      }
      delete a
      delete b
    }
    NR > 1 && $1 != prev {sort(l, v); i = 1}
    {v[i] = $3; l[i++] = $0; prev = $1}
    END {sort(l, v)}' file
PB.1060.1_1_1000        Chr1      1       293     20733996       
PB.1060.1_1_1000        Chr1      287     485     20733577      
PB.1060.1_1_1000        Chr1      484     817     20733209        
PB.1060.1_2_1001        Chr1      286     484     20733577
PB.1060.1_2_1001        Chr1      483     816     20733209
```

We first define function `sort` that takes two parameters: `a` is the array of all lines with the same first column and `b` is the array of their third columns. Both arrays are indexed numerically, starting from 1.

`asort(b, c)` copies array `b` to array `c`, sorts `c` by its content, re-indexes `c` it from 1 and returns the number of elements. The two nested loops print the lines sorted by the third column.

Of course this could exhaust the available memory if you have a very large number of consecutive lines with the same first column. If it is the case a solution based on splitting your file in as many files as you have different first column values, sorting them separately, and re-concatenating them, would probably be your best option:

```sh
$ awk -vi=0 '
    NR == 1 || $1 != prev {i += 1; n = sprintf("x%010d", i); prev = $1}
    {print > n}' file
$ for f in x*; do sort -n -k3,3 -o $f.sorted $f; done
$ cat x*.sorted > file.sorted
$ rm x*
$ cat file.sorted
PB.1060.1_1_1000        Chr1      1       293     20733996       
PB.1060.1_1_1000        Chr1      287     485     20733577      
PB.1060.1_1_1000        Chr1      484     817     20733209        
PB.1060.1_2_1001        Chr1      286     484     20733577
PB.1060.1_2_1001        Chr1      483     816     20733209
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you complete reply. That helps.

Comment: Note that this really preserves the order of the first column, whatever it was, while the other answers re-sort the data set by first column. If the first column was already version-sorted the result will be the same, else it will be different. May I suggest that you edit your question and clearly state that the first column is already version-sorted and should remain so, instead of asking for a solution that _should keep the order of the original file_ without explaining what it is? This would make your question more accurate and thus more useful.

Comment: I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sort -k1,1 -k3,3n input`:

```
$ cat input
PB.1060.1_1_1000        Chr1      484     817     20733209
PB.1060.1_1_1000        Chr1      1       293     20733996
PB.1060.1_1_1000        Chr1      287     485     20733577
PB.1060.1_2_1001        Chr1      483     816     20733209
PB.1060.1_2_1001        Chr1      286     484     20733577
$ sort -k1,1 -k3,3n input
PB.1060.1_1_1000        Chr1      1       293     20733996
PB.1060.1_1_1000        Chr1      287     485     20733577
PB.1060.1_1_1000        Chr1      484     817     20733209
PB.1060.1_2_1001        Chr1      286     484     20733577
PB.1060.1_2_1001        Chr1      483     816     20733209
```

Comment: How are you sorting that first column?  Do you want to use the digits after the final underscore (`-t_ -k3,3`) or between the 2 (`-t_ -k2,2`)? Either way, `sort` really doesn't allow you to use different delimiters.

Comment: I edited the post. The first column should stay in the order of the original file. I should sort the 3rd column for each occurence of the first column.